# How do I read a delimited file with strings/numbers with Octave?

Tags: io, octave

I am trying to read a text file containing digits and strings using Octave. The file format is something like this:

> A B C
> a 10 100
> b 20 200
> c 30 300
> d 40 400
> e 50 500

but the delimiter can be space, tab, comma or semicolon. The textread function works fine if the delimiter is space/tab:

`[A,B,C] = textread ('test.dat','%s %d %d','headerlines',1)`

However it does not work if delimiter is comma/semicolon. I tried to use dklmread:

`dlmread ('test.dat',';',1,0)`

but it does not work because the first column is a string.
Basically, with textread I can't specify the delimiter and with dlmread I can't specify the format of the first column. Not with the versions of these functions in Octave, at least. Has anybody ever had this problem before?

Answer (score 14):

[`textread`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/textread.html) allows you to specify the delimiter-- it honors the property arguments of [`strread`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/strread.html).  The following code worked for me:

```
[A,B,C] = textread( 'test.dat', '%s %d %d' ,'delimiter' , ',' ,1 )
```

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't find an easy way to do this in Octave currently. You could use `fopen()` to loop through the file and manually extract the data. I wrote a function that would do this on arbitrary data:

```
function varargout = coltextread(fname, delim)

    % Initialize the variable output argument
    varargout = cell(nargout, 1);

    % Initialize elements of the cell array to nested cell arrays
    % This syntax is due to {:} producing a comma-separated 
    [varargout{:}] = deal(cell());

    fid = fopen(fname, 'r');

    while true
        % Get the current line
        ln = fgetl(fid);

        % Stop if EOF
        if ln == -1
            break;
        endif

        % Split the line string into components and parse numbers
        elems = strsplit(ln, delim);
        nums = str2double(elems);

        nans = isnan(nums);

        % Special case of all strings (header line)
        if all(nans)
            continue;
        endif

        % Find the indices of the NaNs 
        % (i.e. the indices of the strings in the original data)
        idxnans = find(nans);

        % Assign each corresponding element in the current line
        % into the corresponding cell array of varargout
        for i = 1:nargout
            % Detect if the current index is a string or a num
            if any(ismember(idxnans, i))
                varargout{i}{end+1} = elems{i};
            else
                varargout{i}{end+1} = nums(i);
            endif
        endfor
    endwhile

endfunction
```

It accepts two arguments: the file name, and the delimiter. The function is governed by the number of return variables that are specified, so, for example, `[A B C] = coltextread('data.txt', ';');` will try to parse three different data elements from each row in the file, while `A = coltextread('data.txt', ';');` will only parse the first elements. If no return variable is given, then the function won't return anything.

The function ignores rows that have all-strings (e.g. the 'A B C' header). Just remove the `if all(nans)...` section if you want everything.

By default, the 'columns' are returned as cell arrays, although the numbers *within* those arrays are actually converted numbers, not strings. If you know that a cell array contains only numbers, then you can easily convert it to a column vector with: `cell2mat(A)'`.